# SQL Result Set Merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a limitation where I can only send one result set to a reporting application at any one time, to produce an end report for a customer.

So a query like this

```
select  
    [AGENT],
    [TRANSDATE], 
    [RECIPT NO],
    [CUSTOMER NAME],
    [ORDER NO] ,
    [TRANS NO] ,
    QUANTITY, 
    [AMOUNT COST],
From [Customer] C
```

However I need lots of totals at the bottom such as this query for some of the columns. I cannot make any changes to front end due to it being a legacy reporting application.

```
select
    Sum ( QUANTITY ) as [SUM OF QUANTITY] , 
    Sum ( AMOUNT COST ) AS [SUM OF AMOUNT COST]
From  [Customer] C
```

Obviously I simplified the queries I am using. So the question is how to make 2 results sets one result set in SQL?

`Union` and `union all` failed due to date columns being defaulted if you use blank for a column in end application.

`Rollup` or `Pivoting` or CTE I kinda thought of but cannot see a solution yet.

Comment: Are you trying to add a row to the bottom of the result set with the totals or do you mind adding more columns to the result set?

Comment: Needs to be totals only for 2 fields . Totals need to be added to the bottom of the result set . I think its not possible at the moment but keeping my mind open.

Comment: Nope in that case it's not possible.  You either need to add a row and 'use' two of the existing columns to have your new values in and ignore the rest OR you need to add the total columns on to every row (ie same value for every row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about windowed functions?

like...

```
select  

[AGENT],

[TRANSDATE], 

[RECIPT NO],

[CUSTOMER NAME],

[ORDER NO] ,

[TRANS NO] ,

QUANTITY, 

[AMOUNT COST],

Sum ( QUANTITY ) over () as [SUM OF QUANTITY] , 

Sum ( [AMOUNT COST] ) over () AS [SUM OF AMOUNT COST]


From [Customer] C
```